# Symfony php Custom exception controller not working

Tags: php, symfony, routes, controller, symfony4

I'm trying to create a custom exception controller in php Symfony 4. Essentially what I want to do is to have a default route that gets called when no other routes match.

I'm trying to follow the suggestions here:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/error_pages.html#custom-exception-controller

I've created the twig.yaml file inside configs>>pacakges:

```
twig:
    exception_controller: App\Controller\ExceptionController::showException
```

I've also created the ExceptionController class:

```
<?php
namespace  App\Controller;


use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class ExceptionController
{

    public function showException()
    {
        $response = new Response();
        $response->setContent("Some random text");
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        $response->setStatusCode(200);
        return $response;
    }
}
```

When I visit a url that does not exist I'm expecting to see the text "Some random text" but instead I get the default symfony not found page:

[image]

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: I had another look at this - I was able to create a new Symfony 4 instance and override the exception controller without any issue. One thing I noticed in your question: you said you created a twig.yaml - this should exist already. Also, you said you created it under `configs` - this should be `config`. Can you clarify the path of your twig.yaml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned that you created a `twig.yaml` under `configs/packages`.

Two things:

1. This should be `config`, not `configs`
2. `twig.yaml` should already exist, there is no need to create this file.

My suspicion is that if you created this file, you've created a file in the wrong place and Symfony is not picking up your configuration change. Instead, add your configuration change to the existing `twig.yaml` file under `config/packages`.

Once you add your custom `exception_controller` path to this existing (assumed default) `twig.yaml` it should look something like this:

```
twig:
    default_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/templates'
    debug: '%kernel.debug%'
    strict_variables: '%kernel.debug%'
    exception_controller: App\Controller\ExceptionController::showException
```

I tested this with a fresh install and it works as expected.

Hope this helps :)

---

<strike>Your method should be called `showException` and not `endpoint` as you defined in your `twig.exception_controller` configuration.</strike>

Comment: I've actually tried that as well but it did not work. Will update the original post with "showException"

Comment: Thank you, this post led me to find the answer. The documentation on setting up the exception controller only applies to symfony projects created using symfony/website-skeleton and not symfony/skeleton. The latter which is used for just setting up the minimum project for api calls.

Comment: Interesting. Good to know! Glad you have it sorted :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use routing for routes ? [Rooting](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/routing.html)

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by routing for routes? If you are are referring to mapping end points to urls all my main endpoints are mapped.